# How to quit program before window opens?

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible not to start the window and quit the program silently? 
   I am thinking to quit a program (will pop up a window , ask if you want to do something) if conditions are not satisfied.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Xcode: In the interface designer select the window and then look at the attributes panel - see the check "Show at Launch"? Uncheck it.